# I'm having an error querying a GraphQl endpoint using Vue-apollo library

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

I'm new to GraphQL.

I'm getting an error " {message: "Cannot query field "id" on type "Query".", locations: [{line: 2, column: 3}]}"

when I query my GraphQl this way. I'm making use of the Vue-apollo library.

```
apollo: {
    products: {
      query: gql`
        query products($currency: Currency) {
          id
          title
          image_url
          price(currency: $currency)
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        currency: "USD",
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: probably server problem ... does it (query+variables) work in graphiql/playground ?

Comment: @xadm yes it does